# Is there another stereo processing node in ROS but stereo_image_proc?

Tags: stereo, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

to compare performance and results I am looking for another node but stereo_image_proc doing stereo image processing.

Curious about your answers,
Sabrina

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9460/is-there-another-stereo-processing-node-in-ros-but-stereo_image_proc?/) by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2011-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sabrina,

you can browse all the existing software directly on the ros website: [here](http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php).

I had a quick look and found these packages that could potentialy do the trick:

- [bumblebee_stereo](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=bumblebee_stereo)
- [stereo_image_proc_gpu](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=stereo_image_proc_gpu)
- [stereo_gpu](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=stereo_gpu)
- [stereo_anaglyph](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=stereo_anaglyph)
- [stereov4l2](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=stereov4l2)
- [sparse_stereo](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=sparse_stereo)

Hope it helps

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2011-03-17**:
A lack of documentation can be a closed-source issue as well ;). As good maintenance and support are important criteria for me I can't consider undocumented packages.

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-17**:
I guess this is when the open-source side of ROS kicks back :) You might want to try compiling the packages and try running some nodes. I usually get the main points of a node by looking at his subscriptions and outputs directly in the code or via rxgraph.

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2011-03-17**:
Thank you for your answer. stereo_anaglyp seems to create cyan-magenta 3D-images. I assume that the *_gpu packages use a graphical processor unit to run the computation but this is not what I am looking for. Unfortunately there are no wiki pages for the other packages you mentioned.